# android: Prevent tab switch unless data saved

Tags: android, android-tabhost

**EDIT: I want to prevent the user from switching tabs unless i get a response for my alert to save data**. I have a onTabChangedlistener to check data change when switching tabs.

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()==1 && dataModified){ 
            AlertMessage(this, "Your data was NOT saved! Press Ok to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current screen. ");
        }

    }}
```

Using onPause also gives the same result..tab switches before the user can respond ok/cancel.

My problem is that by the time the alert shows the tab is already switched. I want the user to respond ok/cancel and then only do the required(stay on the tab or switch tab).

**How can i get the user response and then only allow switching of tabs.**

Thanks

Comment: "I want to prevent the user from switching tabs unless the data is saved" -- then don't use tabs. Use some other UI that offers more friendly UX.

Comment: Is it not possible to prevent users from switching tabs...maybe by using ontouch or ontabchanged listeners

Comment: I am saying that your proposed UI is user-hostile. Get rid of your tabs. Use something else that will not tease users about things they are supposed to do but cannot do because some random developer doesn't want them to do that right now. For example, if your expectation is for users to move from tab to tab in sequence to edit something, create a wizard using a `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: I have not used viewflipper ..would it have to be used in conjunction with tabhost or will have to be implemented separately

Comment: Would it make a difference if i have 3 separate activites as supposed to using only one activity with all the implementation

Comment: @CommonsWare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2206/discussion-between-jayp-and-commonsware)

Comment: i found a work around ...save the data on all the screens using only one save click. And if data is modified on any of the screens then will prompt a message to save data when going back to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to extend the TabHost class and override the setCurrentTab methods then you could add your own onBeforeTabchanged() callback.

Comment: can you provide an example for this